# Are decision trees sparse or dense?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Are decision trees or game trees such as [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive-form_game) sparse or dense?

[This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) goes on about calling trees "tight". Is that dense or a third type?

Also if the graph is sparse, must its matrix representation also be sparse and vice versa?

I'm really lost, please help

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599143/what-is-the-distinction-between-sparse-and-dense-graphs). Since the number of edges in your tree(s) with $n$ nodes is greater than $n$, the trees are in fact dense.

Comment: Well the maximum number of edges I can have in a 16-node tree is 15. I think it is always 1 less edge than the number of nodes. That must mean the trees are sparse. Which also means I made a mistake counting my edges, it is 15, not 14.

Answer (score 0):

Decision trees are sparse.

I figured it out empirically. With my limited knowledge of math, I know that dense graphs have most nodes connected and spares have very few. I made a realistic decision tree of 16 nodes, as dense as I could make it up. Then I put it in a matrix. In a 16x16 matrix (256 cells) there were only 15 connections (5.9%). Would be 30 connections (11.8%) if I made it symmetric, which is unnecessary. Very few no doubt.